# Google Play Subscriptions any way to determine how many devices a user has the app on?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play-services, in-app-billing, subscription

I am getting ready to implement a subscription app for the first time, and if i am reading the documentation properly, once subscribed the user will have access to the app under the standard model for all devices that are registered with the same main account.  Is there any way to query how many devices a user has registered with google play?

Maybe I am being paranoid, but seems like a business could purchase countless devices, and as long as they all had the same main email account on them would only need to purchase 1 subscription... am I awrong?

Comment: From what I've seen, Google Play automatically tracks individual devices regardless of what account is used.  So, if I install an app on my phone and my tablet, with the same account, it still registers as 2 seperate devices.  You might want to consider adding Analytics to your app for better tracking.

Comment: I understand play recognizes its 2 devices, but if I am reading the docs right, this user could theoretically install and use it on thousands of devices with a single subscription as long as they are all using the same account... Am I wrong?  Is there a way to limit how many devices can use the app per subscription to prevent this sort of thing?